# How to duplicate the document in photoshop via scipt

Tags: photoshop-script

I am new to scripting and I am stuck where I would like to duplicate the document in Photoshop via scripting so that document not get corrupted.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope the following code helps you

```
function duplicateDocument() {
    var idDplc = charIDToTypeID("Dplc");
    var desc25 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    var idDcmn = charIDToTypeID("Dcmn");
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
    var idFrst = charIDToTypeID("Frst");
    ref1.putEnumerated(idDcmn, idOrdn, idFrst);
    desc25.putReference(idnull, ref1);
    executeAction(idDplc, desc25, DialogModes.NO);
}
```

For more scripting help you can follow the following link
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2019.pdf

Comment: Thankyou for the quick response. Is it possible to duplicate multiple documents?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but before duplicating all the documents, the best practice is to duplicate one document, process it and then move to the second document.